# Pandas issue pulling a number from a string input from a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with the contents:

```
StrainMax 0.125
StrainMin -0.125
cycles_sec 10
time_percent 50
```

I read it in with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Strains_SI.csv', index_col=None, header=None)
```

Then this:

```
StrainMax = df.iat[0,0]
StrainMin = df.iat[1,0]
cycles_sec = df.iat[2,0]
time_percent = df.iat[3,0]
print(StrainMax)
print(StrainMin)
print(cycles_sec)
print(time_percent)
```

And what I get is this (I believe these are strings):

```
StrainMax 0.125
StrainMin -0.125
cycles_sec 10
time_percent 50
```

But what I want is this:

```
0.125 (I want an float here)
-0.125 (I want an float here)
10 (I want an integer here)
50 (I want an integer here)
```

Is this possible?

I tried numerous Pandas commands and can't get it. I am expecting floats and integers of the numbers only.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. Did you read the docs (e.g. [user guide on CSV files](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#csv-text-files)) and are you aware of the `sep` parameter? If yes, what commands did you try exactly? And regarding the integers, are you aware that Pandas converts numeric columns to a common dtype? That means you'd get all floats.

Comment: *"I believe these are strings"* -- You can use `type` to check that. You can also use Pandas' `DataFrame.dtypes` or `Series.dtype`, but that'd just say "object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice there are no commas in your CSV file. If you check the [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m85lH.png) for the `.read_csv` method, you'll see that it does by default expect a comma separator. If you don't actually have comma separation, it can be useful to specify the actual separator to save effort later. Here we can read in the file using a space as the separator:

I saved your data to `data.csv` (I could have done `data.txt` just as easily.)

```
StrainMax 0.125
StrainMin -0.125
cycles_sec 10
time_percent 50
```

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=' ',header=None)
```

[image]

Note that I also set `header=None` so that the first row of the file would be treated as data and not column names. In this case, pandas makes up column names `0` and `1`.

You can see that it separates the label from the numerical value right away so you don't have to do that manually with each string. The extra convenient thing about that is that pandas now sees an entirely numeric column. If we look at `df.dtypes` we now have:

[image]

The column labeled `1` is now of type `float64`. Your four float values are then accessible by `df[column][row]` as in: `df[1][0]` `df[1][1]` `df[1][2]` `df[1][3]`

---

To be a little slicker in your usage, we can go a bit further. Instead of just telling pandas to not use the first row as headers, we can instead tell it what each column is and even set the name of the measurement as the index for convenience:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=' ',names=['measurement','value'])
df.set_index('measurement',inplace=True)
```

[image]

Now you can get at your data quite nicely with `df.loc['StrainMax']['value']` to get `0.125` (which is indeed a float).

PS. If you ever find that pandas didn't set the data type of a column correctly, you can force the type. In this example, it would be

```py
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(float)
```